# Iterating through two arrays in one loop?

Tags: loops

What am I doing wrong here?

```
for i in x and j in y:
    if checkSquare(BpeicePosition, (i, j)) or checkSquare(WpeicePosition, (i, j)):
        print('yep')
    else:
        print('nope')
```

Throws:

> NameError: name 'j' is not defined

Comment: you should specify the programming language you're using via tags.

Comment: When asking a code related question, it is necessary to include a tag for the specific language you're using. Please [edit] to provide that tag so that someone can help you.

Comment: looks like you are trying to use one `for` statement to run two loops ... do you actually need two loops?

Comment: Lol nvm. Just use zip().

Comment: ps I tried to add a python tag and it said I couldnt do that so... yeah

Comment: No, it didn't say you could not. That doesn't happen. There are thousands of python tagged posts here. Just [edit] your post, go to the tags entry, and type *pyth*, and then choose the appropriate Python tag from the ones displayed to you. The only way it would say that you couldn't is if you were trying to create a new tag, because you don't have the privilege to do so.